# Implicitly convert an Iterable to Option

Tags: scala

I have a requirement in which I want to implicitly convert and Iterable to Option. The requirement is if the Iterable is empty I return None otherwise I return Some(iterable).

The code below

```
implicit def toOption[T](iterable: Iterable[T]): Option[Iterable[T]] = if (iterable.isEmpty) None else Some(iterable)
val opt = List(6,7,8).toOption
```

I am getting compile error 'value toOption is not a member of 
 List[Int]'

What am I missing here?

Comment: It doesn't work like that, you are trying to invoke `toOption` like if it were a method of `List`, which isn't, maybe you wanna read up on the [pimp my library pattern](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-2.10-implicit-class-example) which allows you to use that kind of syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit conversion alone is not going to help you if you want to do this. What you need here is an [implicit class :](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html)

```
object Rich {
   implicit class RichIterable[T](it: Iterable[T]){
     def toOption: Option[Iterable[T]] = if(it.isEmpty) None else Some(it)
   }
}

scala> import Rich._  
import Rich._

scala> List(1,2,3).toOption  
res0: Option[Iterable[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))

scala> List().toOption  
res1: Option[Iterable[Nothing]] = None
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the calling syntax wrong (toOption is not a method on list this way, it's a top level method/function) and you need to be less specific in your type (so it will work with implicit conversions etc):

```
  implicit def toOption[I <% Iterable[_]](iterable: I): Option[I] = if (iterable.isEmpty) None else Some(iterable)
  val opt1: Option[List[Int]] = List(6,7,8)
  val opt2: Option[List[Int]] = List()
```

Here I used a view (<%), meaning as long as the argument can be coerced or transformed to the `Iterable type`, it's ok.

Also you can also write the assignment like this:

```
val opt2 = List(): Option[List[Int]]
```

And here is some documentation on views:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/views.html